# How can I have numbers with a custom format in an ordered list in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-lists

I'd like to have a custom format of numbers in an ordered list in a HTML document. It's nothing specific right now, but these are ones that I wanted in the past or may want in the future:

- with a colon at the end:

  > 1: one
  > 2: two
  > 3: three
- in binary:

  > 1. one
  > 10. two
  > 11. three
- as Mayan numerals:

  > one
  >  two
  >  three

They are examples of how this list would be displayed:

```
<ol>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ol>
```

The format can be set in CSS to one of the predefined ones by setting `list-style-type`, but this is very limited and I can't find a way to customise the number format in any other way.

I imagine that the formatting would be done by a Javascript function that would get the number and return its format as a string, but I don't know how I can use Javascript in CSS.

How can I do that? Is it even possible?

Comment: For the first one at least, you could use a custom css counter, it would be pretty straight forward.

Comment: I know that. I'm interested in a more general solution. The first example is the least important one. I'm interested mainly in that the numbers would be expressed in systems with different bases, which is represented mainly by the second example.

Comment: Well, then you'll need javascript, because `list-style-type: binary` is far from being cross-browser.

Comment: @AmauryHanser Where did you get `list-style-type: binary`? I never mentioned that, and I mentioned `list-style-type` at all just to express that it isn't viable.

Answer (score 0):

- With a colon at the end:

  1: One

  2: Two

  3: Three

  4: FOUR

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

ol {
  list-style:none;
  counter-reset: ol-ten-base-counter;
}
ol li {
  counter-increment: ol-ten-base-counter;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
ol li::before {
  margin-right: 0.2rem;
  content: counter(ol-ten-base-counter)":";
}



body {
  padding: .5rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

</style>
<body>

<ol>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>

</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

---

- In binary:
  A) One way is to use javascript and make a function as below to change base 10 to base 2: (It can be written even better based on the framework you use)

  ```
  <ol>
        <li value={Number(1).toString(2)}>One </li>
        <li value={Number(2).toString(2)}>Two </li>
        <li value={Number(3).toString(3)}>Three </li>
   </ol>
  ```

  B) One way is to use CSS but this code works in binary only until 100 after that it will be 10 base again. if you need more, you have to provide t

  ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>

   <style>
   @counter-style binary-ol {
       system: fixed;
       symbols: '1' '10' '11' '100' '101' '110' '111' '1000' '1001' '1010' '1011' '1100' '1101' '1110' '1111' '10000' '10001' '10010' '10011' '10100' '10101' '10110' '10111' '11000' '11001' '11010' '11011' '11100' '11101' '11110' '11111' '100000' '100001' '100010' '100011' '100100' '100101' '100110' '100111' '101000' '101001' '101010' '101011' '101100' '101101' '101110' '101111' '110000' '110001' '110010' '110011' '110100' '110101' '110110' '110111' '111000' '111001' '111010' '111011' '111100' '111101' '111110' '111111' '1000000' '1000001' '1000010' '1000011' '1000100' '1000101' '1000110' '1000111' '1001000' '1001001' '1001010' '1001011' '1001100' '1001101' '1001110' '1001111' '1010000' '1010001' '1010010' '1010011' '1010100' '1010101' '1010110' '1010111' '1011000' '1011001' '1011010' '1011011' '1011100' '1011101' '1011110' '1011111' '1100000' '1100001' '1100010' '1100011' '1100100'
   }


   ol{
      list-style-type: binary-ol;
   }
   </style>

   <body>

   <h1>The p element</h1>

   <ol>
       <li> One </li>
       <li> Two </li>
       <li> Three </li>
       <li> Four </li>
       <li> Item 2 </li>
       <li> Item 2 </li>
       <li> Item 2 </li>
       <li> Item 2 </li>
       <li> Item 2 </li>
       <li> Item 2 </li>
       <li> Item 2 </li>
       <li> Item 2 </li>
   </ol>

   </body>
   </html>
  ```

---

- Mayan numerals (I am not sure if it is called like this haha)

  : One

  : Two

  : Three

  : FOUR

  ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <style>

   ol {
     list-style:none;
   }
   ol li {
     margin-bottom: 1rem;
   }
   ol li::before {
     margin-right: 0.2rem;
     content: "";
   }



   body {
     padding: .5rem;
     font-family: sans-serif;
   }

   </style>
   <body>

   <ol>
     <li>One</li>
     <li>Two</li>
     <li>Three</li>
     <li>Four</li>

   </ol>
   </body>
   </html>
  ```

Comment: Your solution to Mayan numbering doesn't work. The list items always have “” in front of them. They are supposed to have “”–“” for numbers 1–19, then “”, et c..

Comment: Your solution A to the binary numbering would look fine probably, but I think that it's a hack because the attribute value of li is supposed to take a decimal number, so the actual numbering would still be decimal but with a lot of values skipped.

Comment: Also I understand what this solution is supposed to do, but I couldn't get it to work. It seems that the Javascript code in the braces is supposed to be executed, but I don't know how would it be executed.

Comment: @matj1As I said it depends on the frameworks/ libraries you use, if you use React.js {Number(1).toString(2)} will work but if you use other frameworks/ libraries or vanilla JS then you need to change it a bit.